# Strange "Functions are not valid as a React child"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a context with a dummy component. Here's the component:

```
  const values = useContext(CurrencyContext)
  const valuesItems = Object.keys(values).map(value => {
    return <div key={value} data-testid={value}>{values[value]}</div>
  })

  return(
    <>
      {valuesItems}
    </>
  )
}
```

With this code I hope to get access to the values from the context. As it is I'm getting the error, but **when I change values[value] to something else the warning stops**.

Comment: what is the value of `values[value]`?, try to console it out and see.

Comment: Good point. You helped me to figure it out. In fact there's a expected function within values.